# Exact solution of $u_t(t) = 1-\left(u(t)\right)^3; u(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a code which I believe solves 
$$u_t(t) = 1-\left(u(t)\right)^3,$$
with initial condition $u(0)=0$.

Is there a way to compute the exact solution, so I can check it's correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation is separable:
$$
{du \over dt} = 1 - u^3,
$$
so
$$
{du \over 1 - u^3} = dt,
$$
now integrate on both sides with appropriate integration limits.

Comment: Ok, so it turns out the solution for $u(t)$ is given by solving: $\frac{1}{6} \left(2 \sqrt{3} \tan^{-1}((1 + 2 u)/\sqrt{3}) - 2 \log(1 - u) + \log(1 + u + u^2)\right) - (\frac{1}{6} (2 \sqrt{3} \tan^{-1}((1 + 2*0)/\sqrt{3}) - 2 \log(1 - 0) + \log(1 + 0 + 0^2)))=t$, which matches the solution my code gives. Awesome, thanks!